# probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-theorem, poissons-equation

[image]

I would really be grateful if someone could answer me promptly. I believe i should use the poisson distribution model because that is the suitable one however i cannot satisfy the condition of 'specified interval' which is the case for poisson. I cannot also find the average mean and calculate probability. so i thought of binomial but again the same probability condition is not satisfied.

I am very much sure that this is related to Probability distribution but which model that i am not finding out.

Can anyone help me out?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $X$ of dust particles in the filters is a discrete random variable that counts number of occurances (dust particles) in a specified interval (filter). Thus, it is a reasonable assumption that it can be probabilistically described by the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So i believe i am right about thinking it as a poisson distribution model.

Comment: How can i test whether my this model suggestion is valid? use poisson formulas and calculate probability for P(X=4) etc.?

Comment: yes, Poisson is correct. You need to calculate the $\lambda$ which is simply the sample mean. But you are not asked to do the calculations. However you can do them and compare the theoretical probabilities (P(X=4) etc) with the observed ones, as in $\chi^2$-goodness of fit test.

Comment: Thank you really. I would greatly appreciate if you can provide me simple example of what exactly is X2 - goodness of fit test and how to calculate it? I want to understand the concept well :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the explanation of goodness of fit test does not "fit" in a comment... It is really a straightforward concept, so do not worry, if it will be due in the lecture you will have no difficulties to understand it.